# Making comments/posts show both on my site and on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, web, social-networking

Is it possible for people who are visiting my website to leave comments/posts which are visible/posted both on my site and on my Facebook page?

So if a user types in my site a comment such as "your site sucks big time" I want that post to exist both in my site (in a comments page for example) and in my site's Facebook page.

The comments plugin seems just to add a comments functionality in my website.
The embedded posts plugin does the opposite. Is there some combined functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with the Comments Plugin, you could listen to the edge event for creating a new comment but it does not get you access to the contents of the comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2

There is only one way to do this: By creating your own commenting system and by authorizing every user who wants to comment. Since you probably want the comments to show up as posted by that user, you would need to authorize the user with the "publish_actions" permission. You need to get that permission approved too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

So, the steps are:

- Create your own commenting system
- Authorize users who want to comment ([FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.2))
- The user should be able to decide (with a checkbox, for example) if he wants his comment to show up on Facebook too
- After posting in your custom commenting system, use the [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed) endpoint of your page for posting
- ...or use the [comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments) endpoint of a specific page post